# Does a Romanian omletă ţărănească (peasant omelette) have standard ingredients?

Tags: eggs, omelette, romanian-cuisine, balkan-cuisine

I am currently travelling in Romania and have been enjoying a breakfast each morning of "[omletă ţărănească](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=omlet%C4%83%20%C5%A3%C4%83r%C4%83neasc%C4%83&hl=en&lr=lang_en&safe=off&biw=853&bih=447&tbs=lr:lang_1en&prmd=ivns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=3VQdTtvQK4bFswbOo62yDQ&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CCAQ_AUoAQ)", which can be translated to English as "peasant omelette".

[image: omletă ţărănească]

What I'm wondering is whether it has a standard fixed list of ingredients or is it one of those dishes where you throw in "whatever is laying about" (or at least typical Romanian ingredients laying about).

The one I just ate seemed to contain at least tomato, mushroom, bits of bacon, and those pale green bell peppers common in the Balkans.

There doesn't seem to be an article on it in Wikipedia and I've seen it on the menu of two restaurants in the same small town which makes me think it should be a typical dish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from [search results](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=omlet%C4%83%20%C5%A3%C4%83r%C4%83neasc%C4%83&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=ivns&source=lnms&ei=T5MdTueaIYmmsQKJo_C9CA&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=1&ved=0CCoQ_AUoAA&biw=1280&bih=756) and the handy firefox [babelfish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/babelfish-instant-translation/) addon, the peasant (or country-style) omelette seems to be, as you suspected, one of those dishes where anything handy is thrown in.

**EDIT**: the firefox addon is actually unnecessary as google provides an option on the search results page for translated versions of the search results.